# Joining INTO many-to-many table (From Primary Key Table)

Tags: mysql

This is how far i have gotten, though i don't think it can be done with 1 SQL-statement, i just want to confirm whether or not it is possible to do this with ONLY 1 statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN users_mentors ON users_mentors.id=users.mentoruser_id
INNER JOIN mentor_types ON (mentor_types.id=users_mentors.mentor_type OR users_mentors.mentor_type IS NULL)
INNER JOIN mentor_geographies ON mentor_geographies.mentor_id=users_mentors.id
INNER JOIN communes ON communes.id=mentor_geographies.commune_id
LIMIT 0,10
```

`users` table with foreignkey to `users_mentors`:

```
+------+---------+---------------+
| id   | user_id | mentoruser_id |
+------+---------+---------------+
| 1886 |    NULL |             4 |
| 1885 |    NULL |          NULL |
| 1884 |    NULL |          NULL |
| 1883 |    NULL |          NULL |
| 1882 |    NULL |          NULL |
+------+---------+---------------+
```

`users_mentors` table (in a many-to-many relationship with `communes`):

```
+----+-------------+
| id | mentor_type |
+----+-------------+
|  4 |        NULL |
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           2 |
|  3 |           3 |
+----+-------------+
```

`communes` table (in a many-to-many relationship with `users_mentors`):

```
+----+--------------+-------+----------+
| id | name         | short | contract |
+----+--------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | KÃ¸benhavn   | NULL  |        0 |
|  2 | Aarhus       | NULL  |        0 |
|  3 | Aalborg      | NULL  |        0 |
|  4 | Odense       | NULL  |        0 |
|  5 | Esbjerg      | NULL  |        0 |
+----+--------------+-------+----------+
```

`mentor_geographies` table (the m2m table that has FK to `communes` & `users_mentors`):

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | mentor_id | commune_id |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         4 |          1 |
|  2 |         4 |          2 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

So my question is:

Is it possible to get all rows from `users_mentors` and a list of all their `commune.type`'s, IF THEY EXIST (if `mentor_geographies` is empty, i want empty list of `commune.type`). In all cases i want the user.

Comment: Unclear. Please create a fiddle with sample data (showing in table form is not enough) and show desured result for that data.

Comment: I'd ask for a fiddle as well - but I suggest you change from inner joins to (left) outer joins - since your foreign key columns contain NULL-values

Comment: Why so many `NULLs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33b19d/3 ...

as I said in the comments - use left join instead of inner join ...

your diagram misses the mentor_types ... so I commented it out.

of course you will get 2 lines for user 1886

For your question regarding all lines of user_mentors - no its impossible if you start building the select with the users table. And as there is no mentoruser_id that points to other lines than the id==4 line in users_mentors.